# print a LinkedList list in order, forward and backwards

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to create a linkedlist with 20 objects in it and then iterate forward through it and then backwards but I cannot figure out how to move backwards through the list, there is not a built in method in the LinkedList class.

I was also wondering if there was a way to randomly generate first and last names.

Here is the class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class Class {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        LinkedList roster = new LinkedList();

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
           Student stu = new Student();
           stu.id = i;
           stu.populateName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a first name"), JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a last name"));
           roster.add(stu);


    }
        Iterator<Student> it=roster.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {

            Student st=it.next();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, st.firstName + " " + st.lastName);
            }




    } 
}
```

Comment: There is a `descendingIterator()` for this. _"Returns an iterator over the elements in this deque in reverse sequential order. The elements will be returned in order from last (tail) to first (head)."_

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html has previous() and hasPrevious() methods

Comment: For your question about generating names, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1658791/1207649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinkedList.descendingIterator()` (which is there since Java 1.6)

here's the javadoc

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this deque in reverse
>   sequential order. The elements will be returned in order from last
>   (tail) to first (head).

Usage

```
    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    ll.add(1);
    ll.add(2);
    ll.add(3);

    System.out.println("Normal traversal");
    for(Iterator<Integer> i = ll.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
    System.out.println("Reverse");
    for(Iterator<Integer> i = ll.descendingIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
```

There is one more way of doing this using `LinkedList.listIterator(index)` method too

```
    ListIterator<Integer> i = ll.listIterator(ll.size()); //creates a ListIterator with starting index as the size of LinkedList, to point to the last element
    while(i.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.println(i.previous());
    }
```

Comment: That really helps, but how do I actually show the names that are entered instead of the info about the spot like ClassName@3A4F1F

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to create an object of my referencing class so I can grab the names that way for(Iterator<Student> i = roster.descendingIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Student st = i.next();

Comment: Better, you can override `toString()` in Student and return the `name` field. And just use `sysout(studentObj);`